# Retrieve the list of data from database using hibernate criteria

Tags: spring, hibernate, java-8, java-stream

I have a table called employee_comp_field, where salary fields are available

```
  comp_field id  | year_id  | compensation_field  
       1                 101         salary            
       2                 101         bonus
       3                 101         pf
       4                 101         allowance
       5                 102         salary            
       6                 102         bonus
       7                 102         pf
       8                 102         allowance
```

Then I have another table where employee salary data get stored emp_compensation against each field. As you can see emp_id 10 has three set of records as he got three time salary hike in the same year(year_id=101), which can be identified by salary_order field.

```
    id  |  year_id  |  emp_id  | comp_field_id  |  amount  |  comp_order
    1        101         10            1           10000          1
    2        101         10            2           1000           1
    3        101         10            3           1000           1
    4        101         10            4           100            1
    5        101         10            1           12000          2
    6        101         10            2           100            2
    7        101         10            3           10000          2
    8        101         10            4           10000          2
    9        101         10            1           15000          3
    10       101         10            2           500            3
    11       101         10            3           150            3
    12       101         10            4           1500           3
    13       101         11            1           13000          1
    14       101         11            2           1300           1
    15       101         11            3           null           1
    16       101         11            4           150            1
```

I want to identify all the employees list with max salary_order
my desire output will be below:

```
    id  |  year_id  |  emp_id  | comp_field_id  |  amount  |  comp_order
    9        101         10            1           15000          3
    10       101         10            2           500            3
    11       101         10            3           150            3
    12       101         10            4           1500           3
    13       101         11            1           13000          1
    14       101         11            2           1300           1
    15       101         11            3           null           1
    16       101         11            4           150            1
```

as emp_id 10 got three time salary hike...so I retrieve the list of records with salary_order 3
and emp_id 11 got one ony so I retrieve that set of records ony with salary_order 1

Can someone please help me here, how to retrieve my desire output using hibernate criteria.

My thought is to first retrieve all the list based on emp_id and then using java stream if we can filter it out to get the desired output.

Please suggest the best possible way.

Answer (score 0):

> The best possible way.

is subjective. It can be the fastest, it can be the shortest. It could be anything.

I will give you an example of how you could build a query in mysql to replicate your output. This might be tricky to solve with Criteria though since the table is being self joined.

```
select a.*
from emp_compensation a
         left outer join emp_compensation b on a.emp_id = b.emp_id
    and a.comp_field_id = b.comp_field_id
    and a.comp_order < b.comp_order
where b.emp_id is null
```